# Pattern match an array

Tags: ocaml

I have a function that returns the minimum of an array.

The function has type:

```
min : int array -> int
```

Its implementation is:

```
let rec min a = match a with
  | [] -> 1000000000
  | x :: [] -> x
  | x :: xs -> let ms = min xs in if x < ms then x else ms;;
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Found min with unexpected type: 
Wrong type int list -> int.
```

So how can I pattern match an array?

Comment: "1000000000" is going to give incorrect results with some inputs, you should find a way which does not involve a magic number.

Comment: You are accessing it the wrong way IMO. You can pattern match on an array with array syntax. But there is no head::tail pattern here. Arrays are made for direct access by index. You could convert the array to a list if you prefer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using list notation in your patterns, which is causing the problem. An array constant looks like this: `[| 3; 4; 5 |]`

An array pattern looks the same, as you would expect:

```
let f = function
| [| |] -> "empty"
| [| _ |] -> "one"
| [| _; _ |] -> "two"
| _ -> "many"
```

Every array pattern matches an array of a particular size. There is no match for an array of at least a certain size. This is in contrast to lists, where this flexibility is available.

Rather than using pattern matching, a more useful way to process your array might be to use `Array.fold_left` or `Array.fold_right`.

Possibly you're used to a language where arrays and lists are more or less the same thing. In OCaml you have to choose which one you want to use.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike lists, arrays are not defined inductively. For example, a list is either an empty list or a pair of an element and another list. Inductive data definitions are nice, as they allow to reason about data inductively, i.e., recursively. The array is a very different data structure, that is defined as a fixed amount of elements of the same type. So, your algorithm will not work for arrays. And the problem is not only with the syntax. You cannot express the minimum value by induction on the array. You need to find some other way to express the minimum, e.g., a minimum of an array `A` of size `N` is such element, `m`, that for all `i, 0 <= i < N` we have `m <= A(i)`. If you follow this definition, then you can implement it directly. Start with the first element as an approximation of the minumum, then proceed to the next element, and if it is less than your current minimum, then update your approximation. Once you checked all elements, your minimum will satisfy the desired property.

What concerning the empty case, then you can either decide that minimum is undefined for the empty array. Tha will make your function non-total, that you can represent explicitly, by making the return type `int option`, or implicitly, by raising an exception, and stating in the comment, that function is defined only for non-empty arrays. Alternatively, you can return the `max_int` as a minimum element for an empty array, since maximal lower bound of an empty set is a maximum value of the universe (`max_int` in our case).

Comment: Regarding `max_int`, this is related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/3768/131235

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct way using Array.fold_left to obtain the minimum number in Ocaml Array:

```
let min a =
  Array.fold_left
    (fun x y ->
      if x <=y then 
        x
      else 
        y )
  a.(0)
  a
;;
```